# Notice: Undefined index: name in C:\xampp\htdocs\php\second.php on line 2

Tags: php

I am begineer in php . as this code i have been practising from tutorialspoint.com. in the site this code has produced the actual result but while running in my localhost it says undefined index : name in C:\xampp\htdocs\php\second.php on line 2.

```
<?php
if( $_POST["name"] || $_POST["age"] ) {
if (preg_match("/[^A-Za-z'-]/",$_POST['name'] )) {
die ("invalid name and name should be alpha");
}
echo "Welcome ". $_POST['name']. "<br />";
echo "You are ". $_POST['age']. " years old.";
exit();
}
?>
<!------------Form----------------->
<html>
<body>
<form action = "<?php $_PHP_SELF ?>" method = "POST">
Name: <input type = "text" name = "name" />
Age: <input type = "text" name = "age" />
<input type = "submit" />
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Use isset() for POST variables

Answer (score 0):

use [isset](http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php) function to avoid `undefined index` error

Use

```
if( isset($_POST["name"]) || isset($_POST["age"]))
```

instead of

```
if( $_POST["name"] || $_POST["age"] )
```

Comment: Thank you Md. Sahadat Hossain. Why does that problem appears ? what is the differences in putting 
if( isset($_POST["name"]) || isset($_POST["age"])) 
and 
if( $_POST["name"] || $_POST["age"] ) , as this code have to be seem working in tutorials point.com why is it so .?

Comment: by using `isset` function you check the key is exists or not in the array

Answer (score 0):

Hello you have written html and php both in same page so first when you load page at that time you will not get any value in `$_POST` so you can try like below code then you will not get error.

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST))
{
if( $_POST["name"] || $_POST["age"] ) {
if (preg_match("/[^A-Za-z'-]/",$_POST['name'] )) {
die ("invalid name and name should be alpha");
}
echo "Welcome ". $_POST['name']. "<br />";
echo "You are ". $_POST['age']. " years old.";
exit();
}
}
?>
<!------------Form----------------->
<html>
<body>
<form action = "<?php $_PHP_SELF ?>" method = "POST">
Name: <input type = "text" name = "name" />
Age: <input type = "text" name = "age" />
<input type = "submit" />
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

in this when first without submit page load it checks if `$_POST` isset then run php code otherwise not. actually php script run line by line so without `$_POST` if you are try to access then you will get error try this code may it helps you.